# Search on Lookup Field that points to Calculated Column in sharepoint programatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

I have a sharepoint list with a lookup column.

For example,  I have

```
LookupColumn
--------------
 Title1_test
 Title2_test
```

I want to create a CAML filter query to search on that lookup column, for example, searching on 'test' should give me the two values in that column.

I am doing this right now:

```
 <Query>
<Where>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name=”LookupColumn”/>
<Value Type=”Lookup”>CalculatedText</Value>
</Eq>
</Where>
</Query>
```

But, this is not filtering the records for me. How can I achieve this?

[Update] I forgot to add that my lookup column points to a calculated field.